# Disable NTP on Juniper SRX-240

Tags: ntp, juniper, junos

I'm trying to shutdown/disable the ntp daemon running on a Juniper SRX-240 (junos 11.4), but the [obvious solution](http://www.juniper.net/techpubs/software/erx/erx40x/swconfig-system-basics/html/system-clock-config6.html) is apparently not valid for this hardware/software combination.

Comment: You mean the NTP server or client?

Comment: Your link above is to an ERX device, totally different OS, that's why its not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you can stop the daemon entirely, but you can just delete the NTP section of the configuration.

From configuration mode:

```
delete system ntp
commit
```

Comment: I've figured that the link in question was related to another device/software version - but thanks for confirming this. I settled on simply firewalling the service of

I'm afraid this will not stop the daemon (just leave it running with no configured hosts), so it will still be vulnerable to the attack outlined here

https://cert.litnet.lt/en/docs/ntp-distributed-reflection-dos-attacks

If I'm wrong about this, then please let me know. Otherwise I will leave the answer unaccepted.

Comment: On SRX kernel interfaces are protected. Under the security zones you can choose which host protocols are allowed to be reached

Comment: Ok, so what I wish to do is not possible.